# Importing a range vs one cell (using a query)

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have the following code which imports a cell-based on it falling in a given date range (set in separate cells).

```
=QUERY({2020!I:I}, 
 "where Col1 >= date '"&TEXT('[H] Target Date'!B7, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
 and Col1 <= date '"&TEXT('[H]Target Date'!B3, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 0)
```

I am now hoping to pull the entire row of data vs the single cell.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY({2020!A:Z}, 
 "where Col9 >= date '"&TEXT('[H] Target Date'!B7, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
    and Col9 <= date '"&TEXT('[H] Target Date'!B3, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 0)
```